# Ratings returned by Google Places API do not match Web UI Ratings

Tags: google-places-api

Since the change to Google+ Places, ratings are based on a scale from 0-30. However, the API still returns the old 0-5 scale ratings. Does anyone know of a way to get the same overall rating data from the API as a user will see on Google+ Places?

Answer (score 0):

Please place a 'Places API - Feature Request' for this [here](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Places%20API%20-%20Feature%20Request).

Answer (score 0):

You could multiply the API rating by 6.